# show disk usage

Tags: files, disk-usage, disk, size

I use this command.

```
df -h
```

and my result is

```
     Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

    /dev/simfs       60G   50G  8.6G  86% /
```

How can i see What files space are occupied ?
file name, path file, file size.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the du command instead? E.g. try `du -sh ./*` to see the totals for each file/directory within the current directory. This can take some time when run from the top of a large/complex filesystem.